# Neural network without matrices

Tags: neural-network

Have you ever seen a neural network without matrices?

I'm asking, because I'm currently building one for educational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrix multiplication is just a simplified notation for a particular set of addition and multiplication operations. You can absolutely represent a neural network without invoking matrix notation, it'll just be really tedious (and it will run slower).

Start with a single perceptron and build your way up from there.